# Moving a Value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

After trawling the web, I still haven't been able to find suitable code for my project.

I am trying to move/copy a number value from one cell to another cell in the same sheet at a predetermined time - i.e 11:55 everyday (I believe this can be done with Project Triggers).

The value is in `F3` and I want to move it to `I4`. I have a list of Days in `H4 -> H10`. I need the values to move down the column as the week goes on (The day names change automatically in the `I` column).

I have come up with the code below, which can move the values, however I am having trouble appending it to the correct column:

```
// function to save data - Average, Min, Max (Telementry)
function saveDataTel() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var avr = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!F3').getValue();
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 9, 4).setValues([avr]);
}
```

Once I have been able to get the code correct I will add the Time-based Trigger.

Does anyone know why this code is coming up with an error?

Thank You.

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. SO cannot recommend "code" and is not a code writing service.

Comment: I have added the research I have done now with the code I am working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## !Trigger Happy

```
function moveDataFromF3TOI4() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg1=sh.getRange('F3');
  var rg2=sh.getRange('I4');
  rg2.setValue(rg1.getValue());
  rg1.setValue('');
}

function setUpMyTrigger()
{
  if(!isTrigger('moveDataFromF3TOI4'))//This prevents you from setting up more than one trigger at a time for the same function.
  {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('moveDataFromF3TOI4').timeBased().atHour(23).create();//This will occur some time between 11 and 12 If you need it better than that you will have to think about it and work a little harder
  }
}

function isTrigger(funcName)
{
  var r=false;
  if(funcName)
  {
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    var allHandlers=[];
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++)
    {
      allHandlers.push(allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction());
    }
    if(allHandlers.indexOf(funcName)>-1)
    {
      r=true;
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just needed to add a '1' next to the 'rg' in line 7.